# Vector to Raster using GDAL (gdal.RasterizeLayer) : Error in Output Raster(generating output raster with NAN values)

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

For rasterizing a vector layer, I have tried  gdal.RasterizeLayer method for converting vector(shapefile) to raster(tiff). But its giving raster output with NAN values(complete black image). I need some help in which where I am doing wrong. And I want to print one attribute value from shapefile to raster & remaining values should be zero in outRaster.

My code ( using Gdal )is

```
    NoDataVal = -9999

    # Open the data source and read in the extent
    inPolygonShp = r"E:\polygons.shp"
    outputRaster=r"E:\OutRaster.tif"
    inGridSize=float(2)/110575      # nearly I am converting to 2 meters gridsize since its in GCS coordinates (vector layer)
    shpDS = ogr.Open(inPolygonShp)
    shpLayer = shpDS.GetLayer()

    # Create the destination data source
    xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax = shpLayer.GetExtent()
    xRes = int((xMax - xMin) / inGridSize)
    yRes = int((yMax - yMin) / inGridSize)
    rasterDS = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(outputRaster, xRes, yRes, 1,    gdal.GDT_Byte)

    # Define spatial reference
    rasterDS.SetProjection(shpLayer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToWkt())
    rasterDS.SetGeoTransform((xMin, inGridSize, 0, yMax, 0, -inGridSize))
    rBand = rasterDS.GetRasterBand(1)
    rBand.SetNoDataValue(NoDataVal)
    rBand.Fill(NoDataVal)

    # Rasterize
    err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(rasterDS, [1], shpLayer, burn_values=[200], options = ["ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE"])

    # for rasterizing with a attribute value of polygon
    # err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(rasterDS, [1], shpLayer, burn_values=[0], options = ["ATTRIBUTE= Height"])
```

Here I feel its generating a raster file but its failed to overwrite with shapefile values.
I need some help in this regard.

Comment: to produce zero in all remaining areas of the raster, i assume the burn_values should be [0]. Also - what is the data type of the column you want to convert to raster values?

Comment: Data Type of the column is an Integer( Ranging from 1 to 10 only) and Burn values I will keep a zero only to get remaining values as zero but still I am not getting the proper Raster Output

Comment: When running the above provided script I get this error message: Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:/erosion_model/erosion_main/test_rasterizing.pyh.py", line 17, in <module> rasterDS = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(outputRaster, xRes, yRes, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte) File "D:\Programs\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 1476, in Create return _gdal.Driver_Create(self, *args, **kwargs)
OverflowError: in method 'Driver_Create', argument 3 of type 'int' Can someone help me out with this please? I know you're supposed to answer and not ask again but it's too specific and redund

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/109465)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/109465)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're pretty much there...but you may not need burn_values, try this:

```
err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(rasterDS, [1], shpLayer, options = ["ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE", "ATTRIBUTE=POLYNUMB"])
```

where POLYNUMB is just an example of a column name in your shapefile that you wish to rasterize.  Note that all_touched=true may or may not be what you want...test it out and look at your edges.