# gdal.rasterizeLayer in QgisPython results in Nan values

Tags: python, gdal, pyqgis, rasterization

I have a vector layer projected in WGS84. I would like to use `gdal.rasterizeLayer()` from the python console to convert it to a raster. I would like to burn values from a field. I followed the [gdal cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#convert-an-ogr-file-to-a-raster) and adjusted the code based on the answer [to this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148427/vector-to-raster-using-gdal-gdal-rasterizelayer-error-in-output-rastergener).

Here is the code I used:

```
import math
import os
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

# 1. Define pixel_size and NoData value of new raster
NoData_value = -9999
x_res = 0.5 # assuming these are the cell sizes
y_res = 0.5 # change as appropriate
pixel_size = 1

# 2. Filenames for in- and output
_in = "D:\...\\polyTry.shp"
_out = "D:\...\\poly2.tif "

# 3. Open Shapefile
source_ds = ogr.Open(_in)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()

# 4. Create Target - TIFF
cols = int(math.ceil((x_max - x_min) / x_res ))
rows = int(math.ceil((y_max - y_min) / y_res ))

_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(_out, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
_raster.SetProjection(source_layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToWkt())
_raster.SetGeoTransform((x_min, x_res, 0, y_max, 0, -y_res))
_band = _raster.GetRasterBand(1)
_band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)


# 5. Rasterize why is the burn value 0... isn't that the same as the background?
 gdal.RasterizeLayer(_raster, [1], source_layer, options = ["ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE", "ATTRIBUTE=id"])
```

The photo below show the output raster with the green input polygons. Note the `Nan` values on the left (legend). I also inspected different x, y_resolutions (0.00416, 0.0833333). Additional attempts include creating a floating point and integer raster at both 32 and 64 bit (signed, e.g. `gdal.GDT_Float64`). All have failed and produced `Nan` values.

Also note that `burn_values = [1]` create a raster with all values set to 0. 
How can it be solved ?

[image: exmaple]

Answer (score 0):

Try to define: 
_raster = None

..in the end to close the new raster dataset.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, edit and expand your answer. Explain the context and behavior of the code modification proposed by you